# Passing objects as parameter to constructor?

Tags: c++, object, constructor

I am having issues with passing an object as parameter to another constructor's class.

```
    class A{
        protected:
            double x;
            double y;
        public:
            A(double f, double d): x(f), y(d){}

    };

    class B: public A{
        protected:
            A a;
        public:
            B(const A &aa): a(aa){} 
    };
```

But at B's constructor, there is an error. 
The error states that I have provided 0 arguments, and the candidate expects 2.

I searched for previous questions like this in StackOverFlow, but the answers that I found, state that what I have coded is correct.
I can't figure the error out. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is quite clear.  A's constructor takes two double parameters.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I have an object as parameter at B, which has two double parameters. Doesn't that meet the requirement?

Comment: @JohnSmith "I have an object as parameter at B, which has two double parameters. Doesn't that meet the requirement?" - No, it does not.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I got it Jesper. Thanks for taking the time to type "No"

Comment: @JohnSmith you asked a simple question that had a simple answer. If you want more detail, then here goes: when you need to construct an object you need to use a constructor and you need to pass said constructor exactly the arguments it takes (or arguments convertible to those types).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you extend from `A` and containing a `A`, you will need to pass arguments to those two `A`:

```
struct B : A {
    B(const A &aa) : a{aa}, A{0, 0} {}

protected:
    A a;
};
```

Comment: didn't think of that. Thank you. I deserve the downvote haha.

Comment: It's okay! What can help with the downvotes may be better formatting, and maybe a little research before ;)

Comment: btw, why did you use struct there?

Comment: Because writing structs are equivalent but usually less verbose. They don't need public for inheritance and I can put every public members first. The result is two `public` keyword less to write. I prefer to read and to write less verbose code.

Comment: Last question: Is there an improvement that could be done so that works without warnings? Because in the solution that you provided I get **warning: ‘B::a’ will be initialized after A a;**

Comment: Search for that or ask another question.